# spring boot security use keycloak sessions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm new to security and I'm trying to understand how to implement proper security without any overkill.

Below are my questions.

1. I don't want to allow 3rd party clients to use my API and hence I don't see any importance of OAuth 2.0. Hence I'm looking to use the sessions generated by keycloak (or Ory Kratos) in my Spring Boot Security.  Any guidance on how to do that.
2. I have come across an application https://opstra.definedge.com/ which security is implemented using keycloak (can see the URL pattern). But in the requests, I can't see any JWT token in the chrome DevTools Network Tab while performing any network requests. I think they are implementing it the way I wanted. Any overview on how it is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not architect at definedge, but I'm pretty sure they do not use Keycloak sessions in Opstra (they would have to run Opstra inside Keycloak servlet for that). It more looks like they use OAuth2 to authenticate users from a **Java client** and that this client has sessions of its own enabled (JSESSIONID cookie for `opstra.definedge.com` VS `sso.definedge.com`). It is quite possible that this java client uses access-tokens to authorize requests to resource-server(s), we just can't see it from the browser.

Restricting the clients allowed to consume your API has little to do with authorization method:

- with basic authorization header, any client with login and password can access
- with Bearer authorization header, any client with a valid token can access (which you already had anticipated)
- even JSESSIONID cookie can be set for any origin (I believe), in which condition any request from the same browser would be authorized, whatever the web client.

Restricting your API clients is more about CORS configuration, which aims at just that: filtering which origins (host + port) can access which resource location (URL)

There is a notion of confidential client in Keycloak where the client must provide a password in addition to client-id to exchange authorization codes for access-tokens, but this does not apply to **rich clients** (clients running on devices you cannot trust): Angular, Vue, React, native mobile apps, etc. code can be reversed enginereed to read that password. But it is possible to configure a **Java client** of your own as "confidential" and as so, allow this client only to get access tokens to query resource-server (API).

OAuth2 comes with much more than just easing multi-client scenarios and JWTs with session-less java applications greatly ease horizontal scalability and fault tolerance. You should read [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers) for a refresher on

- OAuth2 (and its value)
- resource-server security configuration (with CORS)

Comment: I don't know if this is the right forum but could you tell me how to integrate spring security with ory kratos

Comment: I don't know Kratos at all, but it seems to provide with normal OAuth2: https://www.ory.sh/docs/getting-started/ory-cloud-oauth2. Once you have the URLs, just follow the article I linked (replacing Keykloak with Kratos, off course).